# Escape character not working for exclamation point

Tags: autohotkey

I'm new to autoHotKey. I am trying to do a hot string for hw --> Hello, World!
The problem is I cannot escape !. It just does Hello, World -- no exclamation. I have tried the following:'

::hw::Hello, World! 
::hw::Hello, World`! 
::hw::Hello, World\! 
::hw::"Hello, World!"

To no avail. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When the Send command or **Hotstrings** are used in their default
>   (non-raw) mode, characters such as **{}^!+# have special meaning**.
>   Therefore, to use them literally in these cases, enclose them in
>   braces.

```
::hw::Hello, World{!}
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_EscapeChar.htm#Escape_Sequences